# Boot Camp issue - Windows 8 on MacBook

Tags: windows-8, macbook-air

I've installed Windows 8 on my Macbook Air and I'm facing issues with the BootCamp software. On clicking "Boot Camp Control Panel...", i get the following error:

[image]

Its a Microsoft Account User and I'm also the Administrator (only user in the System).

I tried creating a new local user account (Standard privileges) and I was able to open the Boot camp control panel.

The reason I have to access this is to change my trackpad settings (such as bottom-right button to right-click, tap to single click).

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: To clarify, on the Local user account, i was able to make the required changes. I restarted the system and the changes were not reflected in my Administrator account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours of researching on this, I was able to solve the problem:

1. Created a standard user as specified in the question.
2. Changed his account type to Administrator
3. Changed the Microsoft Account user (my main user account) to have Standard privileges
4. Logged off the local (Administrator) account and logged in to the Microsoft Account (Restarted before logging-in, but i'm not sure if that's needed).
5. I was able to change the settings in Boot Camp now! (Weird I know!).
6. Deleted the local user account, since there wasn't a need anymore.

I googled to find that this was faced by many Windows 8 users on MacBook Air, so no, it was not just me!